# reference angles are used for trigonometric ratios, why?

Tags: geometry

I can't understand why the trigonometric ratios are always applied for the reference angles i.e, angle which is made or formed by terminal side of angle in standard position and x-axis

Comment: What do you mean? You can still calculate trigonometric ratios for angles such as $300\pi$, reference angles are used only to simplify calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know how trigonometric ratios are usually defined.

Normally we define trigonometric functions for acute angles using right angled triangle as follows.

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {opp}{hyp} \qquad  \cos \theta = \frac {adj}{hyp}  \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {opp}{adj}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {hyp}{opp} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {hyp}{adj} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {adj}{opp}$$

But we can extend our definitions for even other angles using point $P(a,b)$ on cartesian plane as follows

Definition of trigonometric functions as they are usually defined

Consider a point in cartesian plane in $1^{st}$ quadrant as shown

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad \cos \theta = \frac {a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {a}{b}$$

Now consider another point in $2^{nd}$ quadrant

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad\cos \theta = \frac {-a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{-a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{-a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {-a}{b}$$

As you can see we consider the signed values of x and y in the definition keeping in mind that r is always greater than zero.

similarly we can extend this definition (in other quadrants) for other angles.

so if we rotate the line passing through origin and $P(a,b)$ through an angle of $360^o$ we again reach the same point and hence $f(2\pi + \theta )=f(\theta )$ where f is any trigonometric function.